# CoreData • How to modify a many-to-many-Relationship in CoreData using Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, relationship

I am having two `CoreData Entities` with a `many-to-many Relationship` between them.

Let's call them `Person` & `Book`. And let's call the Relationship Properties `Person.books` and `Book.persons`, both of type `NSSet`.

**Background:** I have difficulties with the implementation of this since you can't directly modify the `NSSet` *(not a `NSMutableSet`)*.

**Question:** How can I modify a `many-to-many-relationship`, for example add a new `Book` to a `Person`?

Comment: There should be methods generated for you to do this, addToBooks and addToPersons

Comment: Like Joakim Danielson said, take a look in your entity files (Usually created for you by Xcode) and you’ll find the methods waiting for you there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks a lot. Haven't known this. Feel free to publish it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create relationships in your model then Xcode will generate methods for getting and setting data through does relationships. For a to-many relationship you will get a getter `<relationship name>` and two setters `addTo<relationship name>`

So in this case you can update the relationships using `addToBooks` and `addToPersons`